# call current route name through ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, routes

I want to call currentRouteName(). I want to use this methid to locale my website. I have simple routing. For example

```
Route::get('/acrticle/{id}',[
        'uses' => 'arcticles@single',
        'as' => 'en.articles.single'
    ]);
```

or

```
Route::get('/artykul/{id}',[
        'uses' => 'arcticles@single',
        'as' => 'pl.articles.single'
    ]);
```

For polish version.this route is nto group with 'pl' or 'en' prefixe and some middleware. Myidea is very simple. When user first time visit my webste I show he window when he can check language and click he button. I send information which language was check. Controller's method change 2 first litter to "pl" or 'en'. It look like this

```
$currentRoute =  Route::currentRouteName();
   $localRoute = $lang . substr($currentRoute, 2);
   if($currentRoute == $localRoute){
       echo 'accept';
   } else {
       return redirect()->route($localRoute);
   }
```

Problem is that $currendRoute has ajaxController method not when I am. How I can do that?

Comment: Hmm... this sound as a logic problem. Maybe instead of treat this call the language route inside of a controller, you can call the correct route directly in your ajax request. You can use conf() to get locale to help you to call the expected route.

Answer (score 0):

I have new idea to solve my problem. I created middleware and in this middleware I create cookie with route name. It works, but now I have a new problem. 
1.I have route's name but I need redirect my website. In controller's method I can use redirect()->route() but in ajax it's not possible sa I need new addres in order to redirect website in jQuery.
2. I need website addres with ID.